# I have dynamically generated table in HTML with a dropdownlist, how to keep the value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Good day to you, so I have a question. I have a dynamically generated table which is something like this

```
Number of students: <DropDownlist 1-3>

Each table has:
Name: <input type="text" value="name">
ClassName: <input type="text" value="className">
```

So basically when the student choose the DDL 2, the form will generate two table, but let's say the fill in the table already then decide to add one more student which they will have to choose 3. The input value for Name and ClassName for the previous two will be lost due to form generate new table.

Is there any method to keep the data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing and adding the three input areas to the DOM, you could always render all three areas and just hide them (so the user does not see them) and disable the inputs they contain (so they are not submitted). When the user changes the dropdown, the old values will still be in the DOM. Here is a working example (using jQuery):

```js
// toggle "disabled" attributes of all input elements 
// contained in the given parent area
function toggleInputsEnabled_(areaSelector, isEnabled) {
  var inputSelectors = $('input, select, textarea', areaSelector);
  if (isEnabled) {
      inputSelectors.removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
      inputSelectors.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}

// shows/enables or hides/disables the student data input areas
// depending on the selected number of students
function toggleStudentInputAreas_(selectedNumberOfStudents) {
  // initially the three input areas are hidden and disabled
   $('#student1Area').hide();
   toggleInputsEnabled_($('#student1Area'), false);
   $('#student2Area').hide();
   toggleInputsEnabled_($('#student2Area'), false);
   $('#student3Area').hide();
   toggleInputsEnabled_($('#student3Area'), false);

   if (selectedNumberOfStudents >= 1) {
       // show and enable inputs for Student 1
       $('#student1Area').show();
       toggleInputsEnabled_($('#student1Area'), true);
   }
   if (selectedNumberOfStudents >= 2) {
       // show and enable inputs for Student 2
       $('#student2Area').show();
       toggleInputsEnabled_($('#student2Area'), true);
   }
   if (selectedNumberOfStudents >= 3) {
       // show and enable inputs for Student 3
       $('#student3Area').show();
       toggleInputsEnabled_($('#student3Area'), true);
   }
}
 
// toggle input areas on dropdown change
$('#numberOfStudents').on('change', function() {
     var selectedNumberOfStudents = $(this).val();
     toggleStudentInputAreas_(selectedNumberOfStudents);
});

// toggle input areas initially
toggleStudentInputAreas_($('#numberOfStudents').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="numberOfStudents">Number of students:</label>
<select id="numberOfStudents">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
    
<div id="student1Area">
  <label for="student1Name">Student 1 Name:</label>
  <input id="student1Name" type="text"></input>
</div>

<div id="student2Area">
  <label for="student2Name">Student 2 Name:</label>
  <input id="student2Name" type="text"></input>
</div>

<div id="student3Area">
  <label for="student3Name">Student 3 Name:</label>
  <input id="student3Name" type="text"></input>
</div>
```